# Routing Inspection

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there any way possible to get the child paths given a path?

I mean given the following routes:

```
map.resources :users do |user|
  user.resources :articles
  ...
end
```

If I give path = "users/1", is there any way to get the routes
users/1/edit, users/1/articles, users/1/articles/new ?

Thanks in advance.
-Satynos

Answer (score 3):

There is a rake task for doing that,

```
rake routes | grep "users"
```

From a nix machine outta do it

If there is something clever you want to do in a Rails app, might be worth checking the source for that under rails / railties

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you are asking but these are what I consider the go to resources for routing:

[Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

[Ruby on Rails routing demystified](http://www.computerworld.com/action/article.do?command=viewArticleBasic&articleId=9060861)

Answer (score 0):

Yep, the route definitions are very accessible.  The following code should get you the list of routes for a specific controller:

```
rts = ActionController::Routing::Routes.routes.reject do |rt|
  rt.defaults[:controller] != "users" || !rt.significant_keys.index(:id)
end
```

You can run the following code in the console to see the routes:

```
rts = ActionController::Routing::Routes.routes.reject do |rt|
  rt.defaults[:controller] != "users" || !rt.significant_keys.index(:id)
end; nil
rts.each do |rt|
  puts "Route: #{rt.segments}"
end; nil
```

The segments are actually broken out into an array also, which means it should be easy to further filter the list to only routes that require a user id.